# How do i set up a mysql database using phpmyadmin 4.0.4.1and Xampp v3.2.1

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to teach myself how to put a MYSQL database on my website. I have never ventured into databases before.[$me='Absolute Beginner']

So far I have successfully installed **XAMPP v3.2.1** and studied the required php coding , now I am ready to learn how to create a MYSQL database.

My research so far has led me to **phpMyAdmin** (PMA) however all the information located thus far on the Web refers to earlier models of PMA and there is no apparent relationship between that information and the set out of the current version (4.0.4.1).

I need to locate a user friendly but comprehensive tutorial on how to do this using this version

Can someone please point me in the right direction

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "my website" ?  Is it located on a host provider's server? I assume that your XAMPP is installed on your local workstation, so any database you create there will have to be exported and imported to your provider's server.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/docs.php), perhaps? By the way, the differences between phpMyAdmin 3 and 4 should be relatively easy to figure out...the interface looks different, but largely functions the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows machine, your xampp folder should be under c:\xampp. You should place your PHP files inside `C:\xampp\htdocs\yourfoldername`. Open XAMPP and start Apache and MySQL and you are good to go ! Apache has good [documentation](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) on how to setup. Try [W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) or [TUTORIALSPOINT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_mysql.htm) or may be [PhpAcademy](http://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy) on youtube, for begineers tutorials. They have it nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your browser and tipe "localhost/phpmysql"
2. You can create you database there
3. open your database and then u can create a table

if u want to make a php or html project u can make a new folder on your "htdocs" folder on your xampp directory

example :

- create a new folder name "phpproject"
- under "phpproject" folder create a file "index.php"
- open the file an than type "Hello World"
- Open your browser and than type localhost/phpproject
  u will see "Hello World" on your browser